# Create post request in wpf and open in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I have a wpf form where I can enter values then perform a post request on a url to send data to the website. But is there a way to open in a browser when performing the post request and not after.

The page rendering determines what values have been posted on load.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        try
        {
            openBrowser();
            byte[] responseArray = webClient.UploadValues(_url, serializeValues(postData));
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray);
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
            byte[] responseBytes = convertResponseStramToBytes(response.GetResponseStream());
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseBytes);
        }WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        try
        {
            openBrowser();
            byte[] responseArray = webClient.UploadValues(_url, serializeValues(postData));
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray);
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
            byte[] responseBytes = convertResponseStramToBytes(response.GetResponseStream());
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseBytes);
        }

private void openBrowser()
    {


        //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(_url);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort out the issue. There is  WebBrowser class with a method called Navigation. This allows you to send post data while opening the browser at the same time.